# Выполнение похожих действий для разных элементов

Tags: qt, c++

Имеется форма в QT с некоторым количество полей ввода и вывода. В соответствии с полем ввода надо вывести в определенное поле вывода. Т.е. все операции абсолютно идентичны, но различаются только именами самих элементов. Например, edit_0 -> label_0, edit_1 -> label_1 и т.д. И по нажатию Enter эти значения записываются.
Вопрос: как это все правильнее организовать? 
Например, хорош ли вариант определить новый класс-наследник QLineEdit и оперделить в нем новую функцию, которая записывает в соответствующий лейбл значение. Если вариант хороший, то как именно сопоставить соответствующие элементы QLabel & QLineEdit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Как вариант**

можно отнаследоваться от QLineEdit и в конструктор помимо родителя передавать QLabel, например так:

```
LineEdit( QLabel *target, QWidget * parent = 0 );
```

либо метод setTarget( QLabel *target ), это как душе угодно ( я бы, наверное, и то и то сделал, и + getTarget :). Затем можно переопределить событие, ну, например, focusOutEvent. И в нем обновлять текст метки. Либо сделать слот updateTarget() и сцепить с ним textChanged Edit'а.

**Еще как вариант**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow( QWidget *parent ) :
    QMainWindow( parent )
{
    setupUi( this );

    connect( lineEdit_1, SIGNAL( textChanged( QString ) ),
             this,       SLOT( updateLabelText() ) );

    connect( lineEdit_2, SIGNAL( textChanged( QString ) ),
             this,       SLOT( updateLabelText()) );

    connect( lineEdit_3, SIGNAL( textChanged( QString ) ),
             this,       SLOT( updateLabelText() ) );

}

void MainWindow::updateLabelText()
{
    QObject *sndr = sender();
    if( sndr ) {
        QString senderName = sndr->objectName(),
                labelName = "label_" + senderName.section( '_', -1, -1 );

        QLabel *label = findChild<QLabel *>( labelName );
        QLineEdit *edit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>( sender() );

        if( edit && label )
            label->setText( edit->text() );
    }
}
```